# Linear Transformations $T$ and $S$ and their Characteristic Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, characteristic-functions

My friends and I cannot figure out this proof.  We have part (a) done, but weren't not quite getting part(b).  We think we need a change-of-basis equation.  Any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The point is that $T$ maps $V$ into $W$.  So, take a basis $\left(w_1,\ldots,w_{n-1}\right)$ for $W$ and take any $x$ in $V\setminus W$ to extend to a basis of $V$.  Then, since $T$ maps all of $V$ into $W$, we can write the image of each basis element ( of the basis for $V$ ) as a linear combination of the basis elements for $W$
$$
Tx=a_{0,1}w_1+\ldots+a_{0,n-1}w_{n-1}\\
Tw_j=a_{j,1}w_1 + \ldots + a_{j,n-1}
$$

Therefore, in this basis, the matrix for $T$ has top row all zeroes.  Then you can use the formula for the characteristic polynomial $p_T(\lambda)=\det(T-\lambda I)$